# Why no image of the North or the South Pole Weather?

Tags: orbital-motion, weather, satellites

I was watching a youtube video which refers to National Geographic and other metereological sources that the US govenrment has banned access to the weather and metereological data of both Poles. What is so irrational about that no data in public userland exists.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&v=YUoE4c1NxaI&NR=1

Comment: Would this be a better fit at Skeptics.SE?

Comment: Clearly they are trying to cover up the entrances to the center of the hollow planet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just running into ill founded conspiracy theories.

[Aviationweather.gov](http://aviationweather.gov/obs/sat/intl/) hosts polar satellite images from NOAA's polar orbiting sats.

Comment: Thanks. 
David: The question more accurately fits in Weather Science or Geological Science. Since there were no StackExchange subgroups, I determined the question for Physical Science. I have a proof of video, not for the skeptics, but to demand a scientific rationale. I hope I have explained the reason for posting. Thanks for closing the topic since Dan Neely's link provides alternate answer to the Youtube link I posted.